# How to flash changed values in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember.js to create a table from a json feed. I have a requirement to flash the values (within a table row) that are changing. How do I do this in Ember.js?

My template is shown below:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each Quotes.quotesController.content}}
        <tr>
            <td class="quote-name">{{name}}</a>
            <td class="quote-code">{{code}}</a>
            <td class="quote-value">{{value}}</a>
            <td class="quote-bid">{{bid}}</a>
            <td class="quote-offer">{{offer}}</a>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Here's the code that fetches and updates the quotes:

```
fetchQuotes: function() {
    var scope = this;
    $.getJSON('/rest/quotes', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, quote) {
            scope.updateQuote(quote);
        });
    });
}
```

Just as a comparison, in backbone.js, I was binding to change events at the attribute level and firing animations in the callbacks. For example:

```
this.model.bind('change:value', this.updateValue);

updateValue: function() {
    var td = $(this.el).children('.quote-value');
    td.html(this.model.get('value'));
    td.animate({color: animationColor}, 200)
      .animate({color: '#000000'}, 3800, 'easeInQuint');
},
```

I don't know if such an approach is possible/recommended using Ember.js.

**Edit:**
I almost have it now. I can handle an event on a table cell and change its color to anything. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nareshbhatia/ewvQF/) jsfiddle - click of any cell in the value column and it will turn red. The only thing I don't know is how to capture a change to the table cell value instead of a click event. Is there any such thing as a change event that I can capture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Y5nG5/) (a modification of an answer another one of your questions). I think from there you can do what you need, but in short you need to make an observer that watches for changes to the property on your controller that is holding the array that you are modifying.

**Edit in response to the 1st comment:**

Here is a working solution in response to that comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/ykL69/

Comment: Thanks ud3323. But I don't quite get how I can get to the table cell that I need to flash from the observer. As far as I can tell, the observer knows about the model property that has changed and from the model I cannot/should not go to the view(s). Incidentally, I came up with a solution at the view level, where I can capture events in the view and directly change the associated view element. The only issue is I don't know how to capture a "change" event at the view level. Please see my edit to the original question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you! Learning a lot from your code. I like how you took out the "tr" tag and changed it to a view.

Comment: These jsFiddle's give me the error: _Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match._